# Obtener formato de fecha específico Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Quiero obtener un formato de fecha determinada recibo : `"15/03/2016"` y quiero obtener este formato `2016-03-15T00:00:00+01:00`

He probado con :

```
  dateStart = new Date(filterDateStart.split('/').reverse().join('/'));
  dateStart = new Date(filterDateEnd).toLocaleDateString();
  dateStart =  new Date(filterDateStart).toISOString();
  dateStart = new Date(filterDateStart.split('/').reverse().toISOString('/'));
```

No me funciona ninguno...

Comment: Por aclarar el escenario: tu entrada es un String que representa una fecha y quieres generar otro String que representa la misma fecha pero en otro formato, ¿es eso?

Comment: Sí,pero en AAAA-MM-DD porque recibo "15/03/2016", el formato me dicen que es ISO

Comment: usa `moment().toISOString();` https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que lo más sencillo para formatear sería usar la librería [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

```js
const FORMATO_ENTRADA = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
const FORMATO_SALIDA = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z';
const fecha = moment('15/06/2018',FORMATO_ENTRADA);

console.log(fecha.format(FORMATO_SALIDA))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

En un proyecto Angular:

- Instalas la librería con `npm i moment`.
- En el fichero (componente o servicio) la importas así:

  ```
  import * as moment from 'moment';
  ```

Comment: una pregunta, lo de . 000z no se puede cambiar para obtener al final +01:00  ??

Comment: A ver qué te parece...

Comment: Gracias, aún estaba haciéndolo xD

Comment: porqué dice que no se encuentra el nombre "moment" ?

Comment: es una librería, tienes que instalarla y añadirla a tu proyecto: `npm install moment`