# Rango de Fechas typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Actualizo :

Tengo varios objetos con fechas de inicio y fecha de Fin.

Al insertar/modificar un objeto, **la fecha de inicio o de fin del nuevo** objeto no puede estar comprendida entre algún objeto existente.

Es decir:
Existe : 06/06/2018-----30/06/2018

El usuario puede meter:

```
04/06/2018-------05/06/2018
02/02/2018------ hasta menor que fecha Inicio del que existe (05/06/2018)
o Mayores: 
31/06/2018--------
```

No se puede meter :

```
 04/06/2018-------07/06/2018 El fin ya está comprendido entre el principio y fin existe.

O

07/06/2018---08/06/2018 porque también está comprendido entre el principio y fin del existe.
```

Código:

```
  validateParamsDates(url, newConfig) {

    return this.http.get<any>(url).pipe(map(param => {

      let messageError = { message: "", showAlert: false };

      let userStart = newConfig.startdatevalidity;
      let userFinish = newConfig.enddatevalidity;

      param[1]['params'].array.forEach(element => {

        if(userStart > element.startdatevalidity && userFinish > element.enddatevalidity
           || userStart <  element.startdatevalidity && userFinish < element.enddatevalidity
           && userStart > element.enddatevalidity
          ){
            console.log('good');
        }else{
         console.log('=(');
        }

      });

      return messageError  ;

    }));

  }
```

¿ Es correcto ?

Comment: Cuál es el formato real de las fechas? Lo que has escrito no compilaría... Si usas `YYYYMMdd` sí se cumple la comparación.

Comment: Este formato me viene en String DD/MM/AAAA

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer lo que comenta @PabloLozano, usar un formato de `YYYYMMdd` para comparar si la fecha es mayor o menor que otra. De esta forma siempre que una fecha sea mayor que otra significará que es posterior.

Comment: Deberías [edit] la pregunta y aclarar los detalles de la implementación. Por otro lado, con lo que [te respondí ayer sobre moment.js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175830/obtener-formato-de-fecha-espec%c3%adfico-angular2/175834#175834), deberías ver lo fácil que es comparar fechas usando esa librería...

Comment: @PabloLozano te comenté que no me funciona el moment, no sé que es. lo puse y salió en rojo.

Comment: Te he añadido más detalles en la respuesta

Comment: @PabloLozano lo he modificado entero

Comment: Con moment validar si una fecha está dentro de un rango de fechas es facilísimo https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range

Answer (score 2):

Como te dijeron, es común el uso de moment.js para abstraer esa capa de la lógica. Sin embargo, también se puede resolver adaptando tus fechas a un formato que cumpla con [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

```js
var fecha1='01/12/2018',
    fecha2='2018-12-01';
    
console.log('fecha 1 se evalúa como', new Date(fecha1).toISOString().split('T')[0]);
console.log('fecha 2 se evalúa como', new Date(fecha2).toISOString().split('T')[0]);
```

¿Por qué en el primer caso transpone el mes con el día? Bueno, ese es el formato en inglés. Y justamente por esa ambivalencia es mala idea usarlo en tu código.

Si tienes certeza de que todas tus fechas tienen la forma `dd/MM/YYYY` puedes transformarlas haciendo una función de normalización:

```
function normalizaFecha(fecha_str) {
   if(/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/.test(fecha_str)) {
     return fecha_str.split('/').reverse().join('-');
   }
   return fecha_str;
}
```

Y con eso puedes hacer una comparación del tipo:

```
if(normalizaFecha(Objeto2.inicio) > normalizaFecha(Objeto1.fin)) {
   throw new Error('Fechas se superponen');
}
```

**Edit:** Si estás usando un plugin de calendario para que el usuario elija su fecha o la ingrese en un campo de texto y, repito, **te consta que viene en el formato DD/MM/YYYY** puedes usar la función que te mostré. Usando [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/known-formats/) podrías usar:

```
moment('01/06/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Para indicarle que interprete la fecha con el formato latino.

En tu caso tienes

```
param[1]['params'].array.forEach(element => {

    if(userStart > element.startdatevalidity && userFinish > element.enddatevalidity
       || userStart <  element.startdatevalidity && userFinish < element.enddatevalidity
       && userStart > element.enddatevalidity
      ){
        console.log('good');
    }else{
     console.log('=(');
    }

  });
```

En ese código pienso que faltan paréntesis para aislar las condiciones ([es mejor usar paŕentesis defensivos](https://books.google.cl/books?id=g80P_4v4QbIC&pg=PA363&lpg=PA363&dq=parenthesize%20defensively&source=bl&ots=6pbmopepQ3&sig=hlHTvFSaXC9Yerlpg_oORhkkK4k&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHpNzW5_PbAhVIW5AKHS22CscQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=parenthesize%20defensively&f=false), dijo Eric S. Raymond hace casi 30 años)

Creo que es más fácil enfocarlo a la inversa:

- Si la fecha de inicio está contenida en el intervalo -> error
- Si la fecha de fin está contenida en el intervalo -> error
- Si el intervalo contiene al rango ingresado -> error
- Si el rango ingresado contiene al intervalo -> error

La tercera condición no es necesario comprobarla porque cae dentro de la primera.

Abstrayendo esto a una fución:

```
function validaRango(nuevoRango, rangoExistente) {

  let iniNuevo = nuevoRango.startdatevalidity,
      finNuevo = nuevoRango.enddatevalidity,
      iniExistente = rangoExistente.startdatevalidity,
      finExistente = rangoExistente.enddatevalidity;

  if (iniNuevo > iniExistente && iniNuevo < finExistente ) {
    return false; // fecha inicio se superpone
  }

  if (finNuevo > iniExistente && finNuevo < finExistente ) {
    return false; // fecha fin se superpone
  }

  if (iniNuevo < iniExistente &&  finNuevo > finExistente) {
    return false; // nuevo rango contiene al rango ya ocupado
  }
  return true;
}
```

Si tus valores para `startdatevalidity` y `enddatevalidity` te consta que vienen en formato `DD/MM/YY` entonces usa la función auxiliar que te pasé:

```
function normalizaFecha(fecha_str) {
   if(/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/.test(fecha_str)) {
     return fecha_str.split('/').reverse().join('-');
   }
   return fecha_str;
}

function validaRango(nuevoRango, rangoExistente) {

  let iniNuevo = normalizaFecha(nuevoRango.startdatevalidity),
      finNuevo = normalizaFecha(nuevoRango.enddatevalidity),
      iniExistente = normalizaFecha(rangoExistente.startdatevalidity),
      finExistente = normalizaFecha(rangoExistente.enddatevalidity);

  if (iniNuevo > iniExistente && iniNuevo < finExistente ) {
    return false; // fecha inicio se superpone
  }

  if (finNuevo > iniExistente && finNuevo < finExistente ) {
    return false; // fecha fin se superpone
  }

  if (iniNuevo < iniExistente &&  finNuevo > finExistente) {
    return false; // nuevo rango contiene al rango ya ocupado
  }
  return true;
}
```

Y en el bucle usas:

```
param[1]['params'].array.forEach(element => {

    if(validaRango(newConfig, element)) {
      console.log('good');
    }else{
      console.log('=(');
    }
});
```

---

## Bonus track para usar moment.js con Angular/Typescript

las versiones recientes de moment.js vienen con definición de tipos por si quieres usar typescript con todas sus validaciones:

```
# instalas la librería
npm i moment
```

Y en tu componente de AngularJS haces:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Luego puedes por ejemplo crear una función que convierta un string con formato `DD/MM/YYYY` a un objeto de tipo `moment.Moment`

```
dateToMoment(date_str: string): moment.Moment {
  return moment(date_str, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
}
```

O bien una que reciba un objeto de tipo `moment.Moment` y lo devuelva como string:

```
momentToString(momentObj: moment.Moment): string {
  return momentObj.format();
}
```

En realidad si quieres pasar de una cadena `DD/MM/YYYY` a una `YYYY-MM-DD` no necesitas usar el tipo `moment.Moment` puesto que la función `normalizaFecha` sería simplemente:

```
normalizaFecha(date_str: string): string {
  return moment(date_str, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format();
}
```

Pero sirve para ilustrar el tipo de dato que Typescript esperaría de un objeto moment.

Comment: yo recibo 2018-08-06T00:00:00+01:00, pero el usuario al poner una fecha, pone DD/MM/AAAA. por tanto mi idea es que coger los datos del servicio y pasarlo a DD/MM/AAAA Y entonces comparar.

Comment: En ese caso podrías modificar la función `normalizaFecha` haciando  `fecha_str = fecha_str.split('T')[0];` y deshacerte de la hora si viene en formato ISO con hora. Luego para esas fechas la expresión regular no se cumple y devolverá `2018-08-06`. Puedes usar la misma función para uniformar ambos formatos de fecha

Comment: Existe un plugin para momentjs para lidiar con tantos de fechas github.com/rotaready/moment-range

Comment: Buena acotación. Aunque de todos modos siempre es bueno saber cómo funcionan las cosas por debajo. El día de mañana puede llegar otro mantenedor para la aplicación y al ver el uso de ese plugin asumir que es una caja negra y no cuestionarse qué está validando.